# Подарит удовольствие вкуса или вкусом?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Сочетание начинок подарит удовольствие вкуса или вкусом"

Answer (score 1):

Эээ, а что Вы вообще хотели сказать?))) Предложение неправильное, что с "вкусом", что с "вкуса". Что значит "удовольствие вкуса"? Удовольствие - это состояние, а не процесс, следовательно, его может кто-то испытывать. Но не вкус же испытывает удовольствие, а человек! То есть, например, "сочетание начинок подарит наслаждение вкусом" или "сочетание начинок имеет удивительный вкус". Вариантов много.